# How do I generate a new Vagrant box based on a .bin or .vdi file?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I want to create a Vagrant box based on the output of another Vagrant box. The first one builds a .bin file. Ideally I would like to create a new Vagrant box based on this file. Something like

```
$ mkdir node2 ; cd node2
$ vagrant init node2 ../build/qMp_3.2.1-Clearance_VirtualBox_x86_factory_20170406-2203.bin --minimal
$ vagrant up
```

However it gives an error

> bsdtar.EXE: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format

I can convert from .bin to .vdi, but it's still not enough to create a Vagrant box.

```
vboxmanage convertfromraw --format vdi qMp_3.2.1-Clearance_VirtualBox_x86_factory_20180325-0702.bin qmp-nycmesh-3.2.1.vdi
```

It still gives the 'error opening archive' message. How do I create a Vagrant box from a VirtualBox disk image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized Vagrantfile is just Ruby so I just used Ruby to generate the VDI and Vagrant to attach the VDI to the box. The only problem is it requires a dummy placeholder box, and after you replace the storage medium, it will never delete the placeholder disk image! I don't know how to fix that.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  latest_bin = `ls -t ../build/*.bin | head -1`.strip
  #latest_bin = Dir.glob('../build/*.bin').sort{ |a,b| File.new(a).stat <=> File.new(b).stat }.last
  vdi_file = 'nycmesh-qmp-openwrt.vdi'
  system "vboxmanage convertfromraw --format vdi #{latest_bin} #{vdi_file}" unless File.exist?(vdi_file)
  config.vm.box = "centos/7" # dummy box
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    # add the newly created build disk firmware
    vb.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'IDE', '--port', 0, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', "nycmesh-qmp-openwrt.vdi"]
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to create a new vagrant environment from an existing .vdi per say, but you can associate a vagrant environement with an existing Vbox machine and then generate a box from the vagrant VM:

Go into the vagrant project directory, then create a file name id in the right place with ther VM UUID:

```
$ cd <vagrant-project-folder> && \
$ echo -n \
$ `VBoxManage list vms \
$  | grep <vm-short-name> \
$  | sed 's/.*{\(.*\)}[^{]*$/\1/'` \
$ > .vagrant/machines/<vm-short-name>/virtualbox/id
```

*If the project only have one VM then  should be equal to `default`.*

It directly inject whatever between {} in the result line of the grep to the file without newline.

**The VM must be up in Virtualbox for the `VBoxManage list vms` to work**

Check if the change was taken into account:

```
$ vagrant status \
> | grep -qE '<vm-short-name>.*not created'
```

If vagrant status return a line with our  and "not created" it means it didn't work, otherwise it's OK and you can then run `vagrant up <vm-short-name>` to get into the VM and test it, tweak it, clean it etc...

Then you can package it into a box:

```
$ vagrant package --output <box-name>.box
```

Add it to the box local repository:

```
$ vagrant box add <box-name> <box-name>.box
```

Cleanup with `vagrant destroy` and rm the work directory.

Then init a new project as with any box:

```
$ vagrant init -m <box-name>
```